# I can't delete this local svn working directory on windows

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to delete just my local working copy (no server changes) and I am getting the following error:

Cannot delete dir-prop-base:  access is denied

Make sure the disk is not full or write protected and that the file is not currently in use.

I have tried using Unlocker but it says that no process has a  handle to this and when I select the "Delete" action from unlocker, nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using tortoise svn, there's a process called TSVNCache.exe - kill it. There's a way to permanently disable it too, but I forget where.

Comment: Another problem I've seen with tortoise is that sometimes you can't (for whatever reason) delete the entire source tree at once. What worked for me was to delete the source tree a bit at a time.

Comment: i tried that but still same issue . . by the way, what is the logic behind deleting a few things at once??

Comment: Thanks for the tips. After killing this process I can remove the folder here on my machine.

Comment: It Worked for me after having deleted other SVN process. Made a clean up and it was OK :)

Comment: I also needed to kill two processes called TortoiseProc.exe in order to delete a directory with this error message.

Answer (score 2):

- Download and install Process Explorer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx
- Find > File Handle or DLL...
- Search for dir-prop-base
- Kill the process that has a handle to it

Comment: Process Explorer may have the same behavior as Unlocker but it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

i found windows explorer seems to hold onto some svn folders even if it's not open on it.
try killing explorer.exe (dont worry, you can bring it back without restarting by just running: explorer.exe)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just closing all window explorer instances and reopening then for some reason I was able to delete.  Hope this helps someone :P

Answer (score 0):

I presume it's not the current working directory for any process running on your machine? (e.g. Command Prompt ;-)

What happens if you type in `rd /s <dirname>` from a Command Prompt in the parent directory?

Comment: if i do the rm from command prompt it just says "Access is Denied"

Comment: Can you call up the security information for that filter (e.g. Security tab of the Properties dialog for the folder) to see whether you have the rights to that folder which you might be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

None of above tips worked for me. I was able to finally rename it by using UnlockIT (http://emcosoftware.com/unlock-it) and killing explorer.exe and wmpnetwk.exe (Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service)!

Thanks to Unlocker (http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) for comparison chart with links to alternatives on bottom of page, though I didn't want to install file extension for Unlocker and the standalone wizard didn't start up for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with your outdated version of TortoiseSVN,
and your TSVNCache.exe process comes back to life too after you kill it, or if you just feel uncomfortable about killing processes or downloading another program,

try what I did:

1. Rather than deleting everything from the root folder, start from deleting by little pieces. (Matt Jacobson's suggestion) Pick a small folder
2. Unversion the folder (TortoiseSVN-Export-'onto itself' http://tortoisesvn.net/unversion.html)
3. Delete it permanently (Shift+delete)
4. Repeat for other folders
5. Unversion the root svn folder too to get rid of the deleted file cache in .svn folder

Answer (score -1):

I booted into Safe Mode with command prompt and used rd /s .svn - that worked!